# tcl utf-8 characters not displaying properly in ui

Tags: oracle, tcl

Objective : To have multi language characters in the user id in Enovia v6

I am using utf-8 encoding in tcl script and it seems it saves multi language characters properly in the database (after some conversion). But, in ui i literally see the saved information from the database.

While doing the same excercise throuhg Power Web, saved data somehow gets converted back into proper multi language character and displays properly.

Am i missing something while taking tcl approach?

Pasting one example to help understand better.

Original Name: Kátai-Pál
Name saved in database as: KÃ¡tai-PÃ¡l
In UI I see name as: Kátai-Pál

In Tcl I use below syntax
set encoded [encoding convertto utf-8 Kátai-Pál];
Now user name becomes: KÃÂ¡tai-PÃÂ¡l
In UI I see name as “KÃÂ¡tai-PÃÂ¡l”

Comment: It's probably your database that is the problem. Which database are you using, Oracle, DB2?

Comment: Note that the Tcl manual only claims Tcl uses Unicode strings to maintain textual information internally; UTF-8 is merely an implementation detail.  So, when you want to send data over a wire (or write it to a file etc) you usually have to convert the text to be saved to an appropriate external representation which is usually done using `[encoding convertto $encname $text]`.  Conversely, when you read, say UTF-8 from somewhere, you have to convert it to Tcl's internal representation using `[encoding convertfrom ...]`.

Comment: Brain, We use Oracle 10 g database. We have verified that Oracle, App server and Collaboration server.have urf-8 setting enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to think in terms of *characters*, not *bytes*. They're different things. Encodings are ways of representing characters as byte sequences (internally, Tcl's really quite complicated, but you shouldn't ever have to care about that if you're not developing Tcl's implementation itself; suffice to say it's Unicode). Thus, when you use:

```
encoding convertto utf-8 "Kátai-Pál"
```

You're taking a sequence of characters and asking for the sequence of bytes (one per *result* character) that is the encoding of those characters in the given encoding (UTF-8).

What you need to do is to get the database integration layer to understand what encoding the database is using so it can convert back into characters for you (you can only ever communicate using bytes; everything else is just a simplification). There are two ways that can happen: either the information is correctly shared (via metadata or defined convention), or both sides make assumptions which come unstuck occasionally. It sounds like the latter is what's happening, alas.

If you can't handle it any other way, you can take the bytes produced out of the database layer and convert into characters:

```
encoding convertfrom $theEncoding $theBytes
```

Working out what `$theEncoding` should be is in general very tricky, but it sounds like it's `utf-8` for you. Once you've got characters, Tcl/Tk will be able to display them correctly; it knows how to transfer them correctly into the guts of the platform's GUI. (And in scripts that you actually write, you're best off replacing non-ASCII characters with their `\uXXXX` escapes, because platforms *don't* agree on what encoding is right to use for scripts. Alas.)

Comment: The statement "sequence of bytes (one per result character)" is not quite correct: this is only true for 7-bit ASCII; more complex alphabets yield multibyte UTF-8 sequences for one source code point.  Cyrillic uses 2 bytes per character for instance.  I've no doubts you know this no worse than me, just wanted to make the phrase more clear.